# C#: Removing an Item from List<String>... and the item is not recognized as a String?

Tags: c#, list, syntax-error

newbie to C# here.  In my code, I want to build a list of strings, then later pop the first element off the front of the list:

```
 1    public class foo
 2    {
 3        public List<String> listo;
 4
 5        public foo()
 6        {
 7            this.listo = new List<String>();
 8            listo.Add("Apples");
 9            listo.Add("Oranges");
10            listo.Add("Bananas");
11            RemoveAndPrintAll();
12        }
13
14        public void RemoveAndPrintAll()
15        {
16            while(listo.Count > 0)
17            {
18                System.Console.WriteLine(this.listo.RemoveAt(0));
19            }
20        }
21    }
```

MS Visual Studio tells me that line 18 has a syntax error, specifically this part:

```
this.listo.RemoveAt(0)
```

The error is [CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503)), which doesn't have a very helpful description:

> Argument 'number' cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB
>
> The type of one argument in a method does not match the type that was
> passed when the class was instantiated. This error typically appears
> along with CS1502. See CS1502 for a discussion of how to resolve this
> error.

[CS1502](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1502) is vaguely helpful:

> This error occurs when the argument types being passed to the method
> do not match the parameter types of that method. If the called method
> is overloaded, then none of the overloaded versions has a signature
> that matches the argument types being passed.

So what the heck?  The root of the problem is this:

1. I create a List, then populate it with Strings
2. Later, I try to remove Strings from the list... only the compiler doesn't think the elements are Strings any more.

If there something special I need to do here?  Why would the compiler not recognize the elements' data type when it comes time to remove them from the list?  Thank you

Comment: [List.RemoveAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat) does not return anything. You will need to get the first element before removig it.

Comment: the popping functionality that you might be looking for is in the Stack type not List. where Pop() both returns and removes the last in item.

Comment: @KlausGütter Ahhh... you are so correct.  I should have put `String name = this.listo[0]; 
 listo.RemoveAt(0)'  If you write that up, I'll credit you with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,

```
listo.RemoveAt(0)
```

will remove the 0th element from the list. It won't remove all elements.

As a simple test, you can use this code to test:

```
    private static void RemoveElementsFromList()
    {
        var list = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "efg" };

        for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        var size = list.Count; // here size = 1
    }
```

You can do this;

```
if(listo != null && listo.Any())
{
    listo.RemoveRange(0, listo.Count);
    var size = listo.Count;
}
```

For push and pop functionality, use Stack however.

Comment: The loop in your RemoveElementsFromList example is wrong. Replace `for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)` by `while (list.Count > 0)`

Comment: thanks @KlausGütter i have fixed the code. i am unable to upvote u unless u edit the answer. i'll upvote the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

[List<T>.RemoveAt(index)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat) does not return anything (it has `void` return type). You will need to get the first element before removing it like

```
while (listo.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listo[0]);
    listo.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

That said, consider using [Stack<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) instead of `List<T>` as @yassinmi pointed out.